# await statement vs. expression

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm following the [await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) tutorial on the MSDN, and I'm trying to figure out the difference between using `await` as a *statement* versus using `await` as an *expression*. This whole async-await thing is bending my mind and I can't find any examples for this particular case.

Basically, I wanted to see how to use multiple `await`s asynchronously, meaning I don't want to have to wait for the first one to complete before the second one begins. This, to me, defeats the purpose of asynchrony to begin with:

```cs
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Using await as an expression
    string result_a = await WaitAsynchronouslyAsync();
    string result_b = await WaitAsynchronouslyAsync();

    // This takes six seconds to appear
    textBox1.Text = result_a + Environment.NewLine;
    textBox1.Text += result_b;
}

public async Task<string> WaitAsynchronouslyAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    return "Finished";
}
```

However, with a subtle change it only takes 3 seconds total for the two "Finished"s to appear, which is what I'd want -- the two `await`s running truly asynchronously:

```cs
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var a = WaitAsynchronouslyAsync();
    var b = WaitAsynchronouslyAsync();

    // Using await as a statement
    await a;
    await b;

    // This takes three seconds to appear
    textBox1.Text = a.Result + Environment.NewLine;
    textBox1.Text += b.Result;
}
```

My question is, why do these behave differently? What subtle point am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, you need to distinguish between *parallelism* and *asynchrony*. In the first case, it could easily still be worth performing the operations synchronously (and indeed the second operation may depend on the results of the first) in order to free up the UI thread etc.

But as for why they behave differently - `await` is *only* an expression. It's the kind of expression which can appear as a statement, but it will behave the same way, just like calling a method which returns a string, but ignoring the return value. You can see that by changing your first code to:

```
// Still takes 6 seconds...
var a = WaitAsynchronouslyAsync();
await a;

var b = WaitAsynchronouslyAsync();
await b;
```

That will still take 6 seconds. The point is that you're only starting the second asynchronous operation *after* you've waited for the first one to finish. In your second example, both asynchronous operations occur at the same time.

You can still do that *and* assign the value to a variable, you just need to remember the awaitables:

```
// This will only take 3 seconds
var a = WaitAsynchronouslyAsync();
var b = WaitAsynchronouslyAsync();
string result_a = await a;
string result_b = await b;
```

So basically, the difference isn't to do with statement/expression - it's to do with whether the sequence is start/await/start/await or start/start/await/await.

Comment: Your last edit made me realize, thanks -- the sequencing is the issue. I should've realized that they're both expressions.

Answer (score 4):

In both situations the await keyword introduces asynchrony. The reason you're seeing the difference is that in case 1 you start both tasks sequentially, where in case 2 you let them run in parallel.

Maybe a step by step explanation of both situations clears things up

```
string result_a = await WaitAsynchronouslyAsync(); 
string result_b = await WaitAsynchronouslyAsync();
```

What happens here is:

- a task (a) is started
- task a is awaited (control is returned to the caller)
- when task a is finished after 3 seconds, the method resumes; task (b) is started
- task b is awaited (control is returned to the caller)
- when task b is finished after another 3 seconds, the text appears

In the second case:

```
var a = WaitAsynchronouslyAsync();     
var b = WaitAsynchronouslyAsync();     
await a;     
await b;
```

- task (a) is started
- task (b) is started
- task (a) is 'awaited' (i.e., control is returned to the caller)
- when task (a) is finished after 3 seconds, task (b) is awaited
- since task b was started roughly 3 seconds ago, it's finished more or less at the same time as (a)
- the text appears